# Should I use AsyncTask or IntentService for my application?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask, intentservice

I have been reading around on internet connectivity with Android and noticed there are different ways to handle this i.e. [`AsyncTask`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) and [`IntentService`](https://d.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService). However, I'm still not sure which one to use. My application is basically a location/trails finder with Google Maps. My internet connectivity will be used to find the nearest trails within a certain radius of the map. So, every time a user moves or swipes the map to a new location then it will update with the nearest trails. It will also add a new trail, and allow the user to rate a trail.

Will `AsyncTask` suffice for this or should I use `IntentService`?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should use an `AsyncTask` for short repetitive tasks that are tightly bound to an activity, like what you're currently trying to do. `IntentService` are more geared towards scheduled tasks (repetitive or not) that should run on the background, independent of your activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me an example of a task that would use IntentService?

Comment: Suppose you save trails for a given region on your app (like "favourites" or similar). If you want to keep them up-to-date then just set up an `IntentService` that would run every day and check for changes on those regions.

Comment: Ah, I see. So I guess it's like Facebook or Gmail notifications on our phones?

Comment: Pretty much, although I'm fairly certain those use push notifications, which are a different thing altogether. It would be like the email application with IMAP/POP3 that checks for emails every x minutes.

Comment: This is wrong information, `IntenetService` cannot run independently of your application, `Service` can.

Comment: @Sarwara , What do you mean ?

Comment: comment says:

    "IntentService are more geared towards scheduled tasks (repetitive or not) that should run on the background, independent of your activity."

But IntentService cannot run if your application is not running, If you want something to run even when application is off, you need Service, not IntentService.

Comment: I do this in some apps: When the app is started I launch an IntentService to update the local data if needed (time since last update , WIFI available etc). The Application always displays what is stored locally. 

When new data is available I use a LocalBroadcastManager to notify the application and it refreshes its views (mostly calls to notifyDataSetChanged on adapter)

In this scenario, an IntentService is a lot better than an AsyncTask Whatever activity that is currently active when data is ready will be notified and can chose to act on the new data or not.

Comment: @Sarwara Please, and how can the activity get result , lets say i sent a message and i need to know if the message has been delivered or not?

Comment: AsyncTask used only for few seconds operations

Answer (score 59):

They can be used very differently for different purposes.

`AsyncTask` is a handy threading utility that can be used if you need to constantly tell the user something or periodically perform operations on the main thread. It offers a lot of fine-grain control, and because of it's nature is very easy to work with in the `Activity` whereas an `IntentService` generally requires using the `BroadcastReceiver` or `IBinder` framework.

`IntentService` can be used very much like an `AsyncTask`, but it's purpose is meant for background downloading, uploading, or other blocking operations that don't need user interaction or main thread.  For example, if you want to download and cache maps, you may want to call an `IntentService` so the user doesn't have to be looking at the app for it to download. Likewise, if you're sending data to your server, an `IntentService` is extremely helpful in this regard because you can start and forget. The user can, say, type a comment in your app then press "send".  "Send" will launch the `IntentService` which gets the comment and send it off in to your server on a background thread. The user could press "send" and leave the app immediately and the comment will, eventually, still reach your servers (assuming no errors of course).  If you did this with an `AsyncTask` in your `Activity` on the other hand, the system could kill off your process in the middle of your exchange and it may-or-may not go through.

Generally speaking, neither are meant for long running applications. They're meant for short, one-off operations.  They could be used for permanent, or long-running actions but it's not recommended.

Comment: What should be used for the long-running operations than?

Comment: A generic Java Thread if it's blocking. You can put it in an Activity or Service depending on the need.  Control the lifecycle using the lifecycle methods to ensure they don't run when they're not supposed to.

Comment: -1: `...An IntentService generally requires manipulating the BroadcastReceiver framework.` No, it doesn't. Please see @Joe Malin's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15168625/109941?

Comment: That was meant in comparison to Asynctask which would use callbacks.  You don't have to use BroadcastReceivers for anything, but that is an approach if you want it to report back to the Activity.  Another approach would be binding since it is at it's core a normal Service.

Comment: You *can* use IntentService for long-running operations. I use it (correctly) for perpetual operations.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering  Wouldn't that mean you'd need a separate Service running for each operation rather than one Service that runs them in parallel?

Comment: No sure, but as stated in the IntentService documentation: "All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- **they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop)**, but only one request will be processed at a time."   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: @ban-geoengineering  Right.  So if you wanted to do two long-running processes, you'd need two running services. The same if you had 5, 8, 10 or more. Although I guess for most cases, it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 22):

AsyncTask doesn't play well with configuration changes or other things that restart the Activity.

IntentService is good for a something that should always be available, regardless of how long it takes to do its work. I prefer IntentService in most cases because AsyncTask is so much more dependent on Activity state.

Some notes:

- AsyncTask is *best* for quick tasks that should go right back to the UI, but it can be used in a variety of situations.
- The statement "periodically perform operations on the main thread" is vague. AsyncTask spawns a new background thread that is *different from* the main thread, and does its work on the new thread. Thus the name AsyncTask.
- An IntentService doesn't require "manipulating" the BroadcastReceiver framework. All you need to do is send a local broadcast Intent, and detect it in your Activity. Whether this is harder to do than an AsyncTask, I don't know.
- IntentService *is* meant to do long-running tasks, which it does in the background.
- AsyncTaskLoader is OK to use, but it's meant to be the base class for CursorLoader, etc.
  If you want to refresh "nearby" trails when users move to a new location, an IntentService is probably better.

Don't forget to check for connectivity before trying to update location.

Answer (score 8):

AsyncTasks are very tightly bound to Activitys and can often cause leaked window errors if you navigate away from the Activity that created the AsyncTask.  But they are great for showing a ProgressBar because you can quickly update the progress percentage.

IntentServices are cleaner and safer.  They are more difficult to implement when you are a beginner Android developer, but once you learn how to start them and handle them you will probably never go back to AsyncTasks!

IntentServices also allow for a more modular design in your app.  I typically create a separate class for all my IntentServices, but for AsyncTasks I create them as an Activity inner class.  If I were to separate out an AsyncTask from an Activity, I would have to pass in the Activity Context and View objects in the AsyncTask constructor which can be messy.

Comment: To overcome the messy problem, couldn't you add an inner Interface to your AsyncTask class. The interface would contain the callback method(s) for the activity to implement?

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned above `AsyncTask` will solve your problem.

But Keep in mind that `AsyncTask` has an important weakness: it doesn't handle well `Activity` 
"refresh" (eg during rotation). It may be a problem if, e.g., user rotate the phone while your  `AsyncTask` is still loading stuff. If this is indeed a problem for you I recommend `AsyncTaskLoader`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html

Answer (score 4):

`AsyncTask` and `IntentService` have many same

- Can execute task in worker thread
- Can run in background
- Keep running till task finished event the activity which started it is destroyed
- Can notify to update UI during task running or after task finish

  - For `AsyncTask` we often use `onProgressUpdate`, `onPostExecute` or if you want you can use `BroadcastReceiver`
  - For `IntentService` we use `BroadcastReceiver`

#### Different

1) Send task while running or after running finish

*Example we have a task is: download file from server base on `fileName`.*

**Using** `AsyncTask`

If we one instance of `AsyncTask`, during execute downloading file A we **cannot** execute download file B `AsyncTask` (since we get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task is already running.`). Also after downloading file A finished, we can not execute download file B (since we get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)`.
To download file B during or after download file A, we need to create new instance of `AsyncTask`.
=> To download file A and file B, we need 2 instance of `AsyncTask` => 2 worker thread created

**Using** `IntentService`

During download file A, we **can** sent intent to download file B => after download file A finished it will auto start download file B => don't need new instance, don't need new worker thread.

If we sent intent to download file B **after** download file A finished? After download file A finished, **IntentSevice** will destroyed (because there is no more task). Therefore, when start download file B, new instance of `Service` is created however no new thread created (service keep using only 1 worker thread which name is defined in `IntentSevice` constructor

2) Implement `AsyncTask` is easier than `IntentService`

**USING**
We will see that `AsyncTask` and `IntentService` have many same so in most case we can use `AsyncTask` or `IntentService`. However

- I often use `AsyncTask` for some task that start, finish, interact with UI in 1 `Activity`
- I often use `IntentService` for some task that can start/finish and interact or don't interact with UI from any `Activity`

This answer is base on my test. Please correct me if I am wrong. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

In short, AsyncTask is meant for short tasks that have to communicate with main thread. IntentService is meant for long tasks that don't have to communicate with main thread.

For more info, check these links

http://www.onsandroid.com/2011/12/difference-between-android.html

https://medium.com/@skidanolegs/asynctask-vs-intentservice-1-example-without-code-5250bea6bdae

https://android.jlelse.eu/using-intentservice-vs-asynctask-in-android-2fec1b853ff4

Answer (score -1):

I agree with @DeeV and @ebarrenechea about Intent service in part that you should use it for task that are not tight bound with Activity like uploading some data to server or storing data from server to database.

But starting from Android 3.0 there were introduced [Loaders API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) Which should replace AsyncTask. So for example for loading list which you should display in Activity is better to use Loader which is designed to handle well all the configuration changes and Activity Life-cycle.

[Vogella loader tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#loader)

Comment: Are you sure Loader should be used for server work? I've never heard of that before and I didn't see anything in the docs or tutorial you linked to that suggested that.